# How to connect to local Firebase-server via Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I really would like to write some integration tests by utilising a local installation of [firebase-server](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server), that would mimic the realtime database server.

I have [installed](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html) it and started it from CLI: 
`node_modules/.bin/firebase-server -p 5000`

But I have trouble connecting to it via Swift.
Following the docs for Firebase, it is required to download the utilise `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the project.  This obviously has to change, as I want to connect to the local server instead.

This is what I have right now in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
var firebaseConfig: String!
        if isRunningTests() {
            // unit test server (idealy local)
            firebaseConfig = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-tests", ofType: "plist")
        } else {
            #if DEBUG
                // staging server
                firebaseConfig = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
            #else
                // production server
                firebaseConfig = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-prod", ofType: "plist")
            #endif
        }

        guard let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: firebaseConfig) else {
            fatalError("Invalid Firebase configuration file.")
        }

        FIRApp.configure(with: options)
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
```

That means for unit tests I load the `GoogleService-Info-tests` plist and connect to a remote test database. How could I instead connect to `ws://test.firebase.localhost:5000` ?  It is not clear to me which variables inside `options` are mandatory and need to be provided.

Comment: Related issue on github: https://github.com/urish/firebase-server/issues/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FIROptions init!(googleAppID: String!, bundleID: String!, gcmSenderID GCMSenderID: String!, apiKey APIKey: String!, clientID: String!, trackingID: String!, androidClientID: String!, databaseURL: String!, storageBucket: String!, deepLinkURLScheme: String!)` method and pass in AppId, bundleId, SenderID from a real app, and then databaseURL, which can be a local URL. You should be able to pass `nil` into the others and be fine (though you may have to silence compiler warnings since they appear to be marked as non-nullable in Swift).

Or you can change the one field in your `GoogleService-Info-tests.plist` to point to the new Database.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  It works generally, but often I see the message `firebase-server Send failed: Error: not opened +0ms` under verbose mode. Generally the `observeSingleEvent()` doesn't work reliably.

Comment: I'd file a bug in the issue tracker on that project (https://github.com/urish/firebase-server) as it sounds like a problem with that, not with Firebase itself. Note that `firebase-server` is an open source project and is not supported by Firebase.

Comment: Sure. Thanks, will do.